# Second monitor not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, thinkpad

I am running Windows 10 on a Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga and my second monitor (connected through ThinkPad OneDock into the monitor with DVI)

Previously on Windows 8.1 the monitor was working perfectly with no problems, I have tried restarting the monitor and reconnecting it, making sure it was plugged in properly and I reinstalled the Intel graphics drivers off Lenovo's website.

I know the monitor is working because when I turn it on I see the welcome screen and I can open the menu

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow this Windows 10 monitor trouble-shooter :
[Set up multiple monitors](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/set-up-multiple-monitors).

If this doesn't help, the Intel Communities website says, on Intel Aug 26, 2015, on the thread
[4400 and Windows 10 - Dual Display](https://communities.intel.com/thread/78895) :

> At this stage after all troubleshooting I would recommend waiting
>   until our engineering department releases a new Windows 10 Graphics
>   driver.

The latest Intel HD Graphics 4400 driver is available on the
[Intel Download Center](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=4th%20Generation%20Intel%C2%AE%20Core%E2%84%A2%20Processors%20with%20Intel%C2%AE%20HD%20Graphics%204400).
Currently the latest Windows 10 driver dates from 8/12/2015,
so keep on checking. Run also Windows Update from time to time and check
the Optional updates section for a new display driver.

Comment: And of course, you wouldn't be the first to downgrade back to Windows 8/7 because of such teething problems with Windows 10.

Comment: from what I have heard it isn't possible to downgrade back.

Comment: So I pretty much just wait? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: The problem is most probably Intel, because external monitor do work with their other display adapters. As the last driver dates from August 12th, it's clearly still under development. Keep on visiting the above Intel website - probably it will be available there before adopted by Microsoft. The HD 4400 is so common, that logic says that Intel is obliged to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Windows 10 equivalent drivers are not allowing the proper drivers to install and take precedent. Lets start with the following steps to correct this:

1. To ensure changes to the driver do not occur without your knowledge, open the Control Panel (right-click Start button and select Control Panel)
2. Navigate to System and Security > System > Advanced system settings
3. Click Hardware tab > Device Installation Settings and select No, let me choose what to do option
4. Select Never install driver software from Windows Update
5. Next. Press the Windows key‌ Windows logo key+X and choose Device Manager
6. In Device Manager, navigate to Sound, video and game controllers
7. Right click on the display driver and choose uninstall
8. Ensure the delete the driver software for this device is checked
9. Download and install the appropriate video driver:
   http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-yoga-series-laptops/thinkpad-yoga
10. Reboot the computer on installation completion.

This should resolve your second monitor issue.